# How can I validate customer login details by checking if they are in my derby database?

Tags: java, database, validation

I have a registration page where customers sign up and make an account. The account details are stored in an Apache derby database. There is an option for customers with existing accounts to log in to the webpage, how can I cross check that they have an account before allowing access to the site?
Below is the code I used to store the details in the dB. I am unsure how I can validate the users and have found nothing helpful online. Thanks in advance.

```
    //using get parameter to get values from index.jsp
String fn=request.getParameter("firstname");
String ln=request.getParameter("lastname");
String ad=request.getParameter("address");
String em=request.getParameter("email");
String ph=request.getParameter("phone"); 
String ps=request.getParameter("password");
String conps=request.getParameter("confirmpass");

//connecting to dB
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/login","reg","reg");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();

//inserting values into dB
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into login values('"+fn+"','"+ln+"','"+ad+"','"+em+"','"+ph+"','"+ps+"','"+conps+"')");
```

Comment: There should be a unique identifier to validate if the customer is already registered or not. You can use the executeQuery method of PreparedStatement to retrieve records from the DB table based on unique identifiers like email or mobile and check if any record is found or not.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet can be used to check data is present in table, based on identifier like email -

```
String em=request.getParameter("email");

// Create a PreparedStatement object 1 
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT count(*) FROM login WHERE email=?");
                             
pstmt.setString(1,em);      // Assign value to input parameter 2 

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

rs.next(); //Moving the cursor to the last row 3

System.out.println("Email id "+ em + " is present in table for " + rs.getInt("count(*)")+" times");
```

Comment: Thats giving me an internal status 500 error

Comment: Please share exact exception or SQL error code

Comment: You can even refer link - https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html where they presented CRUD operation